# cart to show coupon or shopping cart rule with tax

Tags: tax, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, discount

There is major problem with cart and discounts,
it always shows amounts without taxes calculated for it.
For shopping cart rules, coupons etc.

How to manage the code to show discount with correct tax amount added to it right in the cart. This is the only one row in totals that cannot be set to show with tax applied.

Thanks
Tomek

Answer (score 1):

You can change the setting for this in `system > configuration > sales > Tax`

quite simply change the setting in `Calculation Settings` tab

change `Apply Discount On Prices` to including tax.

[image]

Comment: Setting 'Apply Discount On Prices' to 'Including Tax' does not seem to make a difference at all.